# I am looking for an efficient approach to concatenate and merge rows in pandas DataFrame with regard to some criteria

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, bigdata

I am working on a code for a data set in pandas. To simplify my question, suppose L_1={2, 5, 8, 19} (elements in L_1 are sorted in ascending order). I am wondering based on L1, how to generate another set L_2 = {(2,5), (2,8), (2,19), (5,8), (5,19), (8,19)}. Then, based on L2, how to again generate another set L_3 = {(2,5,8), (2,5,19), (2,8,19), (5,8,19)}. Again, based on L_3, how to generate L_4 = {(2,5,8,19)}. So, the based idea of generating L_k from L_(k-1) is that

1) each element in L_k is a k-tuple (a_1,...,a_k) such that a_1 < a_2 < ... < a_k

2) if (a_1,...,a_(k-1)) and (b_1,...,b_(k-1)) belong to L_(k-1), then they can be combined to gather if a_i = b_i, i = 1,..., k-2 and a_(k-1) < b_(k-1). This results in ((a_1,...,a_(k-1), b_(k-1)) as a k-tuple element for L_k.

I am wondering how can I generate the above sets by pandas in an efficient way, since L_1 may have more than 100 thousands elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need:

```
l1 = [2, 5, 8, 19]
l2 = [(i, j) for i in l1 for j in l1[l1.index(i)+1:]]
l3 = [(i, j, k) for i, j in l2 for k in  l1[l1.index(j)+1:]]
l4 = [(i, j, k, l) for i, j, k in l3 for l in  l1[l1.index(k)+1:]]
```

Comment: Thank you zipa. In fact, the number of indices i,j,k, ... can go up to 100k. I try to avoid that.